# How to hide ressource content

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I work with air and generate native application with Flashbuilder (MyApp.dmg).
After [image] installation, MyApp.app exist on application folder.
Then, I can open MyApp.app package and view all script in Resources folder.
Do you know how to forbid access to this file or hide them better.

Thanks!

Comment: You can open what package?  And view what?   What do you want to forbid access to?

Answer (score 0):

Anything you do to protect your code can be circumvented; there aren't solutions to make it impossible to crack, only harder.

Look into obfuscation and importing .swf files remotely.